# How to specify file name when executing query via Athena API client (Boto3)?

Tags: python, boto3, boto, amazon-athena, pyathena

I have a query string and using the `start_query_execution()` method, I'm right now able to run my query via Athena and get the results in the form of a CSV file in my S3 bucket.

However, the file's name is a bunch of random characters and I'd like to be able to give it a name in order to reference it in other applications (e.g. QuickSight).

From what I can see, the `start_query_execution()` method only contains the following parameters: `QueryString`, `QueryExecutionContext`, and `ResultConfiguration` in which I'm providing my S3 path.

How would I be able to give my query results file a specific name?

Comment: Don't think it's possible. Since you have the prefix, just iterate through S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is the Athena query ID. See [Identifying Query Output Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html#querying-identifying-output-files).
You can use that to pass on the S3 path or object name to other applications.

Currently its not possible to give a custom name for the query results file.
You could build a custom process around Athena queries to move and rename the S3 objects after the query completes.